# react-google-maps: Cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, typescript

I am trying to use this library **"react-google-maps"** to display google maps in my application. After having followed the tutorial from their github page, I get this error on first run (this is a create-react-app + typescript application) :

[image]

I am kind of lost here. As any one used this library before? Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, Marker, withGoogleMap, withScriptjs } from 'react-google-maps';
import { compose, withProps } from 'recompose';

const TerrMap: React.StatelessComponent<{
    isMarkerShown: boolean
}> = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=__my_api_key__&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
      }),
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap
)( (props: any) => {

    return (
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />}
        </GoogleMap>
    );
} ) as any;
```

Comment: Add a code snippet instead of a screenshot

Comment: Was this ever answered?

Answer (score 15):

If this hasn't been answered yet. Here is how to fix this.

1. Add these two typing `"@types/googlemaps"` and `"@types/markerclustererplus"`
2. Make sure that you include these types in for project. You can do that different ways, but the easiest would be to add these two types in your `tsconfig.json` file like this.

Sample:

```json
    {
        "compilerOptions":{
            ...,
            "types":[
                ...
                "googlemaps",
                "markerclustererplus"
            ] 
        }
    }
```

This should solve your issue.

**2024 Update**

Type namespace has changed for google.maps
`"@types/googlemaps"` to `"@types/google.maps"`

So, the types to be included in tsconfig.json should look like this (I didn't even have to include "markerclustererplus"):

```json
    {
        "compilerOptions":{
            ...,
            "types":[
                ...
                "google.maps",
                "markerclustererplus"
            ] 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Worked for me, thank you!

Comment: 2021: i had to add "google.maps" not "googlemaps"

Comment: +1 to @xaphod. The @types/googlemaps has been renamed to @types/google.maps (with the dot). Therefore in the types array you also need to type it with the dot.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using typescript you have to install:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps
```

A better description can be found here:
[react-google-maps-cannot-find-namespace-google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772004/react-google-maps-cannot-find-namespace-google)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this notation at the top of the file

```
/*global google*/
```

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

add to eslint config:

```
"globals": {
        "google": "readonly",
    }
```